# Ninject with Log4Net extensions via TaskScheduller no logging output and no error

Tags: ninject, log4net, ninject-extensions

I have a console application project that is using Ninject and Log4Net.

When i run the app on my machine, the logging is working fine. When i run the app on the production server, the logging is working fine. When i run the program via TaskScheduller task which is being set so that is is being run by some other user, i get no logging output by any of the appenders. I'm using RollingFileAppender, SmtpAppender and AdoNetAppender. 
The strange thing is, that the program is running fine, it just doesnt log anything.

I presume that because the app is working if i run it locally, the log4net configuration is fine.

I resolve logger in the main method of the program and then inject it via constructor parameter when needed. This is how i get the logger in the main method of the app:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

var kernel = new StandardKernel();
var loggerFactory = kernel.Get<Log4NetLoggerFactory>();
ILogger logger = loggerFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();

logger.Info(" Test ");
```

Any hints, pointers or anything....as i don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

The extension is normally used like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public MyClass(ILogger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
        log.Info("Created MyClass");
    }
}

XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
{
    kernel.Bind<MyClass>().ToSelf();
    kernel.Get<MyClass>(); // will cause the log message to print
}
```

Just let Ninject worry about injecting the `ILogger` into your class. You can't request an `ILogger` from the `IKernel` in the same place you declare the kernel because you've got no context.

You can do this though:

```
ILogger log = new Log4NetLoggerFactory().GetCurrentClassLogger();
log.Info("Test");
```

Comment: I have changed it to the way you wrote, but i still don't get any logging output when i run the app with task scheduler. I have turned on the Internal debug of log4net and if i run the app with my user, i get a bunch of additional text displayed. But if i run the app via task scheduler, i get no errors in event viewer, and no log output. I can see that the app is running in windows task manager.